# Weird banding in stats simulation results

Tags: javascript, math, web-applications, statistics

So I am currently taking a Statistics course and we have been talking about sampling variation. I constructed a Web App that performs a sampling simulation and displays the results(cobra5707.dx.am/SampleSim) When I use a nice sample size like 1000 I get a good Normal Distribution.

Results for 0.45, 1000, 10000:

[image: Amazing Results]

However when Sample size is not a nice number the resulting histogram has weird gaps in it.

Results for 0.45, 808, 10000:

[image: Ugly Results]

The code is not minimized or anything so you can view source in dev tools, the worker code is:

```
onmessage = function(event) {
  e = event.data;
  var s = 0;
  var p = e.true_value;

  for(var i=0; i<e.sample_size; i++){
      if(Math.random()<p)
          s++;
  }

  postMessage(s/e.sample_size);
}
```

edit 1:
So the process works thus, the worker runs a selected number of simulations and calculates the proportion of those simulations that are successful and returns a percentage [0, 1]. These percentages are multiplied by 100, then stored in an array. Finally a histogram is generated by Plotly from the data. The histogram doesn't seem to be in error as looping through the array confirmed that there were no values in the empty percentage ranges.

edit 2: Upon looking more closely it seems that the gaps are caused because certain percentages are simply not possible, and the xbin size is small enough that these gaps are visible, so I guess I will need to play with that. Sorry for wasting people's time, thought it might be some weird floating point error.

Comment: Explain how you use the posted code to produce the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you seem to have realized, it's because the automatically chosen bin sizes chosen by Plotly don't line up nicely with your data.

The easiest way to see that is to run with a sample size of "3" - there are only four possible outcomes: 0.0, 33.33333333, 66.66666667, and 100.0.

Yet the bins that Plotly chooses are -10 to 10, 10 to 30, 30 to 50, 50 to 70, 70 to 90, and 90 to 110.

The solution is to modify the method `UpdatePlot` so that it's using your sample size to determine the bins; something like this:

```
function UpdatePlot(data, args){
    Plotly.deleteTraces("plot", 0);
    Plotly.addTraces("plot",
        {x:data, type:"histogram", autobinx: false,
         xbins: {start: -50/ss, end: 100 + (50/ss), size: 100/ss}});
}
```